# Improve the accuracy for multi-label classification (Scikit-learn, Keras)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am going to train machine learning models that assign certain tags to a paragraph describing an activity. In my database, for a give paragraph of description (X), there are several corresponding tags related to it (Y). I hope to improve the classification accuracy.

I built several machine learning models through Scikit-learn-learn (such as SVC, DecisionTreeClassifier, KNeighborsClassifier 
, RadiusNeighborsClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier, RandomForestClassifier, MLPClassifier, RidgeClassifierCV) and neural network models through Keras. The best accuracy (harsh metric) that I can get is 47% using OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier).

```
print(X)
0        Contribution to METU HS Ankara Lab Protocols ...
1        Attend the MakerFaire in Hannover to demonstr...
2        Organize a "Biotech Day" and present the proj...
3        Contact and connect with Community Labs in Eu...
4        Invite "Technik Garage," a German Community L...
5        Present the project to the biotechnology comp...
6        Visit one of Europe's largest detergent plant...
...

print(y2)
0                                       [Community Event]
1                 [Project Presentation, Community Event]
2               [Project Presentation, Teaching Activity]
3          [Conference/Panel Discussion, Consult Experts]
4          [Conference/Panel Discussion, Consult Experts]
5       [Conference/Panel Discussion, Project Presenta...
6                                       [Consult Experts]
...
```

...

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb_y2 = mlb.fit_transform(y2)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, mlb_y2, test_size=0.2, random_state=52)

Scikit-learn:
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('vect', CountVectorizer()), ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),('classifier', OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss = 'hinge', alpha=0.00026, penalty='elasticnet', max_iter=2000,tol=0.0008, learning_rate = 'adaptive', eta0 = 0.12)))])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train) 
print("test model score: %.3f" % pipe.score(X_test, y_test))
print("train model score: %.3f" % pipe.score(X_train, y_train))
test model score: 0.478
train model score: 0.801 (overfitting exist! I adjusted the penalty & alpha term, but it doesn't improve much. I don't know whether there is any other way to do the regulation.)

Keras:
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=300, lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
x = pad_sequences(sequences, padding='post', maxlen=80)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Embedding, Flatten, GlobalMaxPool1D, Dropout, Conv1D, LSTM, SpatialDropout1D
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import sklearn

filter_length = 1000

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim= 70, input_length=80))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Conv1D(filter_length, 3, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1))
model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
#model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.1))
#model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))
model.add(Dense(len(mlb.classes_)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

callbacks = [ReduceLROnPlateau(),EarlyStopping(patience=4),
    ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model-conv1d.h5', save_best_only=True)]

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=80,batch_size=500,
validation_split=0.1,verbose=2,callbacks=callbacks)

from keras import models
cnn_model = models.load_model('model-conv1d.h5')
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
y_pred = cnn_model.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred.round())

Out: 0.4405555555555556 (I think the neural network model has more room for improvement. But I'm not sure how to achieve that.）
```

I hope the accuracy reach at least 60%. Could you guys give me some advice on improving my code for Scikit-learn and Keras model?

More specifically, 1. Is there a way to improve the OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier)? 2. Is there a way to improve my convolutional neural network? Or use some form of recurrent neural network? (I tried simple RNN, but it doesn't work well.)

PS: In my way of calculating accuracy, for a description(X) if the model outputs [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1](y_pred) and the correct output is [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0](y_test), my accuracy would be 0 instead of 5/6?

This question is quite long. Thank you guys so much!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Because it's not about coding or programming questions, this question may be off topic for stackoverflow. You may have better help and answers if you narrow your specific questions and ask at the [datascience.se] stack exchange site. That being said, I have a question on you last paragraph: " my way of calculating accuracy..." There is one mathematical way of calculating accuracy, which is correct predictions divided by all predictions. Are you instead thinking of a different metric, such as precision or recall?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Anderson! The reason I emphasize this way is that the Keras' default algorithm for accuracy calculation will give us 5/6, which is not proper for multi-label classification. I would like to use the way that I posted to calculate accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of weak classifiers, you can try to churn them into one strong classifier using [boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning)) techniques, for example AdaBoost. [Here](http://%20https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#classification) you have some techniques to try:

Note that if you don't have enough training data then you might get an overfitted model.